# Выполнить javascript в фоновом режиме на сервере не зависимо от клиента

Tags: javascript

Как мне выполнять функцию javascript каждый 20 - 30 секунд (рандом от 20 до 30) без участия клиента ? Имею обычный хостинг.

Comment: На обычном хостинге выполнять JavaScript на сервере невозможно. Нужен хостинг с поддержкой node.js. А вообще-то задача странная. Лучше напишите зачем Вам это надо.

Comment: Делаю рулетку. После завершения прокрутки мне нужно подождать пару секунд и запустить заново. Есть предложения ?

Comment: @SlavikOkara так алгоритм же относительно простой. Клиент делает ставку, нажимает "крутить" посылается запрос на сервак, который генерирует случайно число и сразу передает на клиент. Клиент уже будет знать заранее это выпавшее число. Анимация на клиенте происходит 25 секунд (прокрутка и остановку рулетки) + 5 секунд еще после остановки.... повторить

Comment: На сайте у всех людей рулетка должна быть едина, т.е. 20 человек делают ставки например в течении 20 секунд, потом крутим рулетку и у всех она одинаковой быть должна.

Comment: @SlavikOkara Не вижу никаких препятствий. вместо кнопки крутить дается 20 секунд сделать ставки после окончания предыдущей анимации игры и дальше автоматом идет запрос если сделана хотя бы одна ставка

Comment: "дается 20 секунд", а кто или что должен давать эти 20 секунд ?

Comment: JavaScript выполняется в браузере, если мы не говорим про Node.js, во-вторых зачем задавать дубликат вопроса?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что явно дубликат вопроса http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478383/Выполнять-js-на-стороне-сервера

Answer (score 0):

Вашу задачу лучше выполнить с применением websocket, что подразумевает использования чего-нибудь отличного от php. Например, node.js, java. Могу даже посоветовать хороший tool-kit для создания веб-приложения на java, [vertx.io](http://vertx.io/). Авторы были вдохновлены node.js, работать с ним удобно и приятно, как раз использую его для одного проекта. А на php эту проблему решить довольно сложно, без костылей не обойтись.

Comment: `Rachet` - не слышали, не?